# Avoid error: Composer requires PHP version (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, composer-php

I'm trying to avoid receiving this error when attempting to use some Google Analytics libraries installed via composer;

**Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.2"**

My PHP version is 8.0.13 but I don't want to upgrade to the latest version (8.1.1) yet because I'm running a few plugins on my WordPress site which aren't compatible with PHP 8.1.1.

I have tried using `"platform-check": false` in my composer.json but it did nothing. I also tried updating to PHP 8.1.1 but obviously the plugins broke.

Any ideas on how to solve / bypass this?

My composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/proj_name",
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    },
    "platform-check": false
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your composer json.

Comment: If the PHP version you are using to run Composer really would be 8.0.13, I doubt that Composer would tell you otherwise. What does `composer diagnose` tell you about the PHP version?

Comment: Running ```composer diagnose``` returns 8.0.13

Comment: composer.json contents added above

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I had php7.4 and php8.0 installed and, I don't know why, but my `composer install` worked properlly and when I launched my app I had the same error as you. I just removed php7.4 and then it worked.

Comment: Perhaps your best shot is to wait till your plugins support 8.1.1